# Unicode Insert does not work in EF6 Migration

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-6

We have an issue with EF6 / SQL Server 2008 when put some insert statements into a migration.

The insert SQL is placed in the `Up` method that contains some special characters as below but they are displaying as `?` on the web in UTF8 encoding.

```
INSERT INTO [Items] ([Id],[Code],[Name])
VALUES (NEWID(), 'transport', 'ả'),
       (NEWID(), 'travel', 'ệ'),
       (NEWID(), 'social', 'ể');
```

If we switch to use C# code on the `Seed` method and creating entities then it works fine. Both Migration file .cs and Configuration.cs file are saved in Unicode UTF8 encoding.

I did some research but couldn't have any good news. Do you know how to make the Migration work? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @restless it is nvarchar for all text columns

Comment: If you are using CodeFirst Approach,you would try deleting all your table and try running it again.

Comment: yeah, it's code first but we want to correct some rows in production already / or add new rows.

Comment: SQL Server stores `NVARCHAR` as UTF-16. There is no UTF-8 support in SQL Server.

Comment: Thanks @TT. for the information. On the web page we use UTF8 and it is displaying correctly for unicode fields entering from the web, but not from SQL script in the Migration.

Comment: It's been way too long since I've been in a .NET environment (it was very low level when I was), so I can't comment on C#/Migration/EF6 (what Migration anyway? that a product?) etc.

Comment: Thanks @TT. for your interest. EF Migrations will automatically execute SQL scripts against the db for us based on latest code.

Comment: If you want to make sure SQL Server uses **Unicode** (`nvarchar`), you **must** provide an `N` prefix before your string literals - use `(NEWID(), N'transport',  N'ả'),`

Comment: Thanks @marc_s, this is exactly the fix !